# NSManagedObject data from coreData to text

Tags: arrays, string, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Im using coreData and I've already fetched the data, but I want to use the results in order to assign the text to a new variable so I can fill a URL.

I want to use the `id` and `token` results, so I can make a variable with the text in them.

**This is my actual code:**

```
   @IBAction func boton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as     AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var datosGuardados = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SparkData")
    datosGuardados.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

    var datosRecuperados:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(datosGuardados, error: nil)!

    println(datosRecuperados)
    println("hay \(datosRecuperados.count) resultados")
    var res = datosRecuperados [datosRecuperados.count-1] as NSManagedObject

    println(res)
```

**and this is what i'm getting:**

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffef1c35eb0> (entity: SparkData; id: 0xd000000000500000 <x-coredata://714BECAF-F850-4C30-86BA-BC29CEB15F90/SparkData/p20> ; data: {\n    id = 7hj54758s29k22f;\n    token = 112586939;\n})"
)

hay 20 resultados

<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffef1c35eb0> (entity: SparkData; id: 0xd000000000500000 <x-coredata://714BECAF-F850-4C30-86BA-BC29CEB15F90/SparkData/p20> ; data: {

   id = 7hj54758s29k22f;
    token = 112586939;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems trivial.

```
var myNewVariable = res.valueForKey("id")
```

BTW, better change the name `id` to something else or you might get into trouble. Try `idNumber`.

Comment: It worked, but now i get:      
Optional(7hj54758s29k22f)  How can I remove the "optional"?

Comment: That is another question. You need to "unwrap" the optional value. If you are sure that it exists, use `res.valueForKey("id")!`, i.e. add an exclamation mark.